# How to show divergence of $\frac{n^2}{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $(x_n)= \left(\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}\right)$.

I tried the problem like, $\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}=\dfrac{n^2-1+1}{n+1}= n-1 +\dfrac{1}{n+1}$

Now the sequence $(n-1)$ is divergent. To prove it suppose in contrary, it is convergent then it must be bounded i.e there exists a real number $M>0$ such that $n-1=|n-1|<M\hspace{10pt}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

(Now here comes a little glitch in my opinion, when $n=1$ I can't apply the Archimedean property, as $n-1=0$.) Neglecting that, I consider $n>1\Rightarrow n-1>0$ and thus by Archimedean property, $\exists p\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow p+1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that,

$(n-1)(p+1)>M \Rightarrow (np+n-p)-1>M$

Since $np+n-p\in \mathbb{N}$ thus contradicts the hypothesis that $n-1<M\hspace{10pt}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence $(n-1)$ is divergent.

From this can I conclude $(x_n)$ is divergent.

Another question, how can I prove that it is divergent, by using the definition only?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}=+\infty$ and thus the sequence is divergent.

Comment: A direct argument can be obtained by finding positive integers solutions of the inequality $\frac{n^2}{n+1}>M$ for each positive integer $M$. This is equivalent to $n^2-Mn-M>0$. So, you can take $n=M+1$.

Comment: $\frac{n^2}{n+1} \gt \frac{n^2 - 1}{n+1} = n-1 \to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disprove boundedness, it suffices to find *one* $n$ with $x_n>M$. You may simly take $n$ with $n>M+1$ (from Archimedean property) and find
$$x_n=n-1+\frac1{n+1}>(M+1)-1+\frac1{n+1}>M. $$

---

To disprove convergence "directly", assume $L\in\Bbb R$ is the limit, take $\epsilon=1$ and note that $x_n>L+\epsilon$ for all $n>|L|+2$, for example.

Comment: So can I suppose $(x_n)$ to be convergent, and then if I show that it is not bounded, I conclude that assumption was wrong, thus it is divergent.